# Entry date field not showing up correctly

Tags: ee2, date, tags, entries

```
<h7>{entry_date format="%F %m %Y"}</h7>
```

This is the code I have for my entries, I want to display the date as to when content was posted. I have 2 videos up right now, their actual dates are Feb 17th and Feb 25th. However with the above code, they both show up on my website as Feb 2nd. So its not a Daylight Savings Time (DST) issue.

I even tried to change entry in the code above to edit and I had the same results. Anyone have an idea of something I can try to get it to display the correct date of entry? Thanks in advance, I appreciate it!

Comment: `<h7>` isn't a valid HTML tag.

Answer (score 4):

Your first 2 tokens are both month tokens. Essentially you're outputting "February February 2013".

Try `%F %j %Y` or `%F %d %Y` instead. ([See PHP date formatting tokens.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php))

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot, probably wouldn't have overlooked that if it would have displayed the type or something. The messed up date made me think I had a problem with the actual tag itself. Thanks again, I appreciate it!